# Error when running tensorflow in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am new to `pycharm, tensorflow and python`. I have this simple program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

To set the tensorflow module i followed this: `settings > selecte 'Add Local' > selected /home/manish/dev/tensorflow/bin/python3.4`. I have my tensorflow installed in `/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/`

I am getting this error:

```
/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/bin/python3.4 /home/manish/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manish/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/manish/dev/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, I can execute the script from the terminal but not from pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Open Pycharm through terminal instead of search bar.

1. Open terminal
2. Execute command: pycharm-community